# T4 templates vs TT Templates vs Includes in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, transform, t4

In visual studio there are 2 types of text transformation templates file extensions `.T4` vs `.TT`

I would like to **know their differences** and wh**ich one I should use when I want extend to build Views Controllers and Models, when I read a schema off a DB**

I also want to know if `.includes` can be reused in both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. Back around 2008 this feature was treated as if it were an add-in (even though it ended up being built into VS directly). Microsoft called it the "Text Template Transformation Toolkit," hence the `.T4` extension. Common usage shortened that to "text templates" yielding the `.TT` extension and this appears to have become the standard extension.

Transformation files are just code, they can use any feature of the language you choose. For example, in C# templates I regularly reference .NET assemblies as follows:

`<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>`